# Google Earth land features importing to ArcMAP

Tags: arcgis-9.3, kml, google, google-earth

I'm wanting to import land features, such as lakes, reservoirs and other land-made features onto my ArcMAP. Is that possible as this is new with my client wanting this done.

What needs to be done as I've been researching this.

Comment: Am I correct, that you need the ArcGLOBE extension to do the KML for Google Earth? I do not have that extension, is there anothe way to go around it?

Comment: No - ArcGlobe is only required if you want it in 3D like Google Earth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use KML to Layer in ArcGIS 10
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/KML_To_Layer/00120000004w000000/

Comment: Oh, I should have stated, I have 9.3, not 10.

Comment: http://www.zonums.com/online/kml2shp.php